# XSD Enumeration integer values

Tags: c#, api, wcf, xsd

I have a simple enumeration which i need to convert to an XSD to give to the client

```
    public enum Categories
    {
        uknown = 0,
        Simple = 100,
        Complex = 200
    }
```

I'm using Visual Studio command line to conver this to a valid xsd but i get the following as a result in my XSD

```
<xs:simpleType name="ProductCompatibilityCode">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="uknown" />
      <xs:enumeration  name="Simple "/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Complex" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

What I need is to keep the integer part of the enumeration, so for example i can get 100 for (int)Categories.Simple etc. Is there a way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlEnumAttribute

```
public enum Categories
{
    [XmlEnum("0")]
    uknown = 0,
    [XmlEnum("100")]
    Simple = 100,
    [XmlEnum("200")]
    Complex = 200
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It creates the enumeration as   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("0")]
Item0,
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("100")]
    Item100,
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("200")]
    Item200,. I need to keep simplem complex as values and only get the integer part when needed